# Parse SBJSON + Syntax

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, parsing

I would lie to parse a JSON file with SBJSON but I've a little problem of comprehension ?
Here is my JSON structure :

- id
- text
- date

So for exemple :

[{"id":"1","text":"blabla","date":"1235432241"},{"id":"2","text":"blabla2","date":"1235432241"}]

And here's the code I found to parse a JSON file whit SBJSON :

```
- (void)downloadJSONFile:(NSData *)data 
{   
    SBJSON *jsonParser = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    id response = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];

    NSDictionary *feed = (NSDictionary *)response;
    NSArray *nodes = (NSArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"keyValue"]; // here's I don't know what to put

    for (int i = 0; i nodes.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *node = (NSDictionary *)[nodes objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"id = %@",[node objectForKey:@"id"]);
    }
}
```

I don't know what to write in the valueforKey of my nodes array ...
Someone can explain to me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keys are: id, text and date. So if you wish to parse the objects with the key id, then in that line which you've highlighted it would be :

valueForKey:@"id"

Comment: So then in my for loop I can ask for text and date keys ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to parse from the JSON response. Your JSON response has those 3 keys. So basically those ARE your keys: id, text and date. valueForKey means fetching the value associated with the key that you mentioned within the quotes in the @" " that follows valueForKey.

Comment: So if you wish to fetch text values alone, use @"text". Same goes for rest

Comment: I just want to print the 3 values in each new entry. So as I understand I can just put whatever I want for the key.

Comment: Right. Do two more NSLog statements in the loop with text and date as keys. And before the that be sure to have created the NSArray first, similar to the node array, again with the other keys

Comment: So ok I understand what you mean for the NSLog (it seems logical ;) ) but I didn't catch you sentence after (NSArray ...). Sorry :s

Comment: I meant duplicate the "line which you have highlighted as not understood" on your post's code section. You need to do that as well with the other 2 keys for the additional 2 NSLogs to print proper values :) If this did help you, please accept the answer as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your supplied json sample you should get an `NSArray` containing two `NSDictionary`. So the code should be

```
NSArray *nodes = (NSArray *)response;
```

Not being familiar with SBJSON it is possible that response actually is an `NSDictionary`. In that case you can just print the dictionary using `NSLog(@"%@", feed);` You should get a print out that looks something like:

```
{
  nameOfKey =  (
              {
               "id" = 1;
               "text" = "blablabla"
...
```

Where nameOfKey would be the keyValue you are looking for.